# I want to input a dictionary as type dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I input this

```
{'Name':'Rick', 'Country':'UK'}
```

This will be taken as a string

What is the procedure to set the type as dictionary?

Comment: use [**`json.loads`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

Comment: It depends on where you input it. If its typed into a .py file, then its a python string literal and its already a dict as soon as the module is loaded. If is read from a file or read from standard input its, well, its whatever you want it to be. If you make a rule that the input is a python literal, then `ast.iteral_eval` would parse it. If the rule is that its JSON, then `json.loads` would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), rather than munging the quotes and applying `json.loads`

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'Name': 'Rick', 'Country': 'UK'}")
{'Country': 'UK', 'Name': 'Rick'}
```

[`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can be used to evaluate strings that express any of the basic types such as `tuple`, `dict`, strings and numbers etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval()`

```
import ast
x=input()
s=ast.literal_eval(x)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
{'a':1,'b':2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```